# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. for HttpWebRequest and WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I'm getting the above error message when i try to get a response from a URL. 
The code i've used is

```
HttpWebRequest ObjContentfulRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
HttpWebResponse ObjContentfulResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ObjContentfulRequest.GetResponse();
```

and I've also tried with

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
              var json = client.DownloadString(URL);
            }
```

Please suggest what i'm missing.   **The error i'm getting is  The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

Comment: Could you please provide more information: What is the url like (https?), is it hosted by yourself, do you have a trustworthy certificate for this url? What happens when opening the url in the browser?

Comment: In the browser it shows 400 bad request. Its a https url. They have given access tokens to access the data. There is no certificates as such.

Comment: The URL format is as below

https://theurliwanttoaccess/myspace/idforspaces/entries?access_token=given accesstoken

Comment: When the url you're trying to open inside your code fails even in the browser, the error does not lay in the code but the url. So before further coding make sure the url is working... either by browser or a tool like "Fiddler2".

Comment: The URL is working fine checked the same in browser and in postman tool

Comment: You just wrote "In the browser it shows 400 bad request"?! Okay, when working well in the browser can you see whether the certificate is valid or not?

Comment: With some research i found the solution for it.... We are using .net framework 4.0 there is not tls1.2 support for it. So if we use this mentioned piece of code, we can get  a response from the URL. 
 **ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;**

Comment: Thanks for the help **OlafW**

Comment: You're welcome, even if my help was not that much! Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

first install Nuget System.Data.DataSetExtensions
then after use HttpWebRequest

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;